# Create Connection Strings with the Factory Pattern

Tags: c#

I have the following code

```
public static DatabaseFactory {
    public DatabaseProvider Create(dataSource, ProviderType provider type){
        //dataSource = "Server\Instance", "MyOracleDB" 

        if (type == ProviderType.Sql) 
            return new SqlDatabaseProvider("$data source = {dataSource}; integrated security = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = True;");

        throw new NotImplementedException("Provider not found"); 
    }
}
```

Doing it this way I have to hard code a connection string for each provider I implement. I'm wondering if there is a dynamic way to retrieve a connection string or build it based on a value.

Comment: Define "better" please.

Comment: @Quality Catalyst updated my response.

Comment: Why is that wrong?  At some point you need to understand the specifics of each connection.  That's pretty much the definition of a factory - the central place that understands the specific cases and returns the general case so the clients don't have to.  After that, where you source your strings from is just programming.  Try a config file?

Comment: @LoztInSpace config file sounds like a better idea instead of hardcoding it in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a factory is to abstract the creation of an object so that the calling code doesn't need to be aware of the specifics, and that you may perform addition operations after construction, and that you may return a subclass of the factory's return type.

So it might be more typical that your calling code is not even aware of the database type. Your code may look more like this:

```
var mainProvider = DatabaseFactory.Create("main");
var backupProvider =  DatabaseFactory.Create("backup");
```

Then your factory might look like this:

```
public static DatabaseFactory
{
    public static DatabaseProvider Create(string key)
    {
        var providerType = GetProviderTypeFromConfig(key);
        var connectionString = GetConnectionFromConfig(key);

        if (providerType == ProviderType.Sql) 
            return new SqlDatabaseProvider(connectionString);

        if (providerType == ProviderType.Oracle) 
            return new OracleDatabaseProvider(connectionString);

        throw new NotImplementedException("Provider not found"); 
    }
}
```

Now you would need to write the code for `GetProviderTypeFromConfig` and `GetConnectionFromConfig` which would go off to some XML/JSON file, or even spin up a DB connection itself, to get the actual values used.

This type of code then becomes easier to test too as each part can be unit tested.